# SWIG: Coping with baseclass overloaded methods in a derived class

Tags: c++, python, inheritance, swig, overloading

I'm struggling to make this somewhat elegant in SWIG...

I have a base class which contains an overloaded method create:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual Foo *create(ClassA &, ClassB &) = 0;
    Foo *create(int id) {
        // get ClassA a and ClassB b from an internal store related to id
        return create(a, b);
    }
};
```

This is of course, SWIG-wrapped without hassle.

In other locations/repositories, there are several different derived classes of Base, which of course define their own version of the pure virtual create(ClassA&,ClassB&) method - but they don't need to define a create(int) variant because the base class version should suffice.

The SWIG wrapping of these derived classes only see the create() method defined in the derived class, and don't provide for the variant with the single int parameter, even though they should inherit it from the baseclass.

I have tried using %rename for the baseclass's methods to get something that works, e.g.

```
%rename (_create1) Base::create(ClassA&,ClassB&);
%rename (_create2) Base::create(int);

%extend (Base) {
    %pythoncode {
        def create(self, a_or_id, b=None):
            if b is not None:
                self._create1(a_or_id, b):
            else:
                self._create2(a_or_id)
    }
}
```

This seems fine in the generated python/_wrap.cc code, but the wrapper for the derived class will just wrap the create() method as if the %renames aren't there.

They *are* in separate .i files, but the derived classes' .i files each import the baseclasses .i file so the python class inheritance is correct, it's just the C++ class inheritance that is somewhat defeated by this overrided method.

Ideally I'd like a solution where I didn't have to insert %rename statements in all of the derived classes' .i files (although I know this would solve the issue), it just means an awful lot of duplicated code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the classes are declared correctly?  Same-named virtual methods in a derived class hide base class methods unless a `using` brings the base function into the derived namespace.  Example:

```
class A
{
    public:
        void func(int a);
        virtual void func(int a,int b);
};

class  B : public A
{
    public:
        //using A::func;
        virtual void func(int a,int b);
};
```

With SWIG and Python I was not able to write:

```
b = B()
b.func(1)    # failed
b.func(1,2)
```

without uncommenting the `using` line above, and the classes didn't work correctly in C++ either.  With the `using`, SWIG correctly exposed the functions to Python and C++ worked, too.

Comment: Worked fine in C++ (and still does), but I solved my SWIG problem by just renaming the overloaded method to something else. I think I know /why/ I'm having the issue, it just seems there's no real elegant solution, oh well. SWIG is somewhat restrictive in what it can handle, and I understand why this is so.

Comment: Actually, I apologise, you are correct about the C++ stuff as well! Didn't notice until now - an instance of the subclass can't see the overloaded method without the using line.

Comment: Glad to help!  If the answer was useful, please consider up-voting and marking an answer correct via the voting tool and check to the left of the answer.